# Ctrl+click on links with click handlers

Tags: javascript, html, browser, hyperlink

I have a link (anchor) that has an href attached to it to navigate to a specific URL say 'www.bla.com'.

```
<a href='http://www.bla.com' />
```

I also have an `click` handler attached to the link that performs some actions and then opens an html view in the same window. Everything works perfectly well.

However, when the user uses 'ctrl+click' to open the link in a new tab/window, the click handler seems to be taking precedence and opens the html view in the same window. But I want to retain the 'ctrl+click' behavior and allow the user open the link in a new tab/window (just as a normal link). How could I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you using in your handler? I tried replicating it and the only thing I could find that stops it was an `alert`

Comment: There are many keys that change the default behavior. You're better off using something like [`filter-altered-clicks`](https://github.com/bfred-it/filter-altered-clicks) to handle it for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
function process(e){
   var evt = e ? e:window.event;
   if(evt.ctrlKey)
      alert("ctrlClicked");
}​
```

evt.ctrlKey will return true if control key is pressed, you can write your conditions within "if" block, I tested this for chrome and ff only.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this?

```
function onclick(e){
   var event = e ? e:window.event;
   this.target = event.ctrlKey?"_blank":"_self";
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

The associated [click event object](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-click) will have its `ctrlKey` property set to `true` if the control key (or equivalent) was pressed when the click occurred. Check the event object and if the control key was pressed, don't do the "HTML view" thing.

```
<a href="#" onclick="alert(event.ctrlKey);">Click me!</a>
```

However, if the user activates the link some other way, you may or may not get a click event.

e.g.

1. right button -> "open in new tab/window"   - no click event (Firefox, IE)
2. Tab to focus on link, press enter - dispatches click event (Firefox, IE)

Answer (score -2):

```
<a target="_blank" href='http://www.bla.com' />
```

Add target="_blank" within to anchor tag.

Comment: that doesn't work, i'm afraid, as _blank opens the link in a new tab/window even on a standard click (not what I want).

Comment: You could add a key listener to detect when ctrl is held down, then simply change the target parameter in according to if it's held down or not. (held ? "_blank" : "_self")