# link normal click open in lightbox, otherwise not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

Well i am not sure if the title fits perfectly, but i have no idea how i could title it.

So to my issue: I want to create a link, when the user clicks normally on it, it should open a lightbox, but if the user wants to open it in a new tab, a different page should be shown. How can i do this?

```
a.btn.btn-info.pull-right.margin-ring(href="/users/create", ng-click="newUser();$event.preventDefault(); $event.stopImmediatePropagation();")
```

Here is my markup. Currently if i click it works fine. The lightbox appears. If i right click on the link and say open in a new tab, everything works fine as well (the href gets opened), but if i want to open it in a new tab, by using Ctrl + Click it is not working.

I guess it has something to do with angularjs and the ng-view, but i am not sure.

I hope someone can help me

Comment: try to catch if the Ctrl key is clicked, and do your redirect. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262669/ctrlclick-on-links-with-click-handlers?rq=1). Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a.btn.btn-info.pull-right.margin-ring(href="/users/create", ng-click="newUser($event);")

//... in controller
$scope.newUser = function(e){
    // if left clicked with no keys held down
    if ((e.which == 1) && !e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && !e.shiftKey) {
        // ... open your popup here
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

EDIT: forgot to pass in the $event object